# 24 hours TimePicker with Focused and Unfocused events

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried implementing 24 Hour `Time Picker` as given here [24 Hour TimePicker](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Time-Picker-as-24-Hours-9e9a2431) in XF project.

But it doesn't fire the `Focus` and `Unfocused` event on Android. Has anyone implemented this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a completed sample: https://github.com/brminnick/24HourTimePicker

[image]

## Explanation

The author of this custom control forgot to fire `Focused` and `Unfocused` in the Android Custom Renderer.

We can fire these events by calling `ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, [true/false]);` from the Android Custom Renderer when `FocusChanged` fires.

This custom Android control also doesn't clear focus once the time is set, so we'll add `ClearFocus()` to `OnTimeSet` too.

## Xamarin.Forms 2.4 Code

Because the sample was written in Xamarin.Forms v2.4, here's the answer if you are continuing with Xamarin.Forms v2.4.

```cs
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;

using TimePickerDemo.CustomControls;
using TimePickerDemo.Droid;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTimePicker24H), typeof(CustomTimePicker24HRenderer))]
namespace TimePickerDemo.Droid
{
    public class CustomTimePicker24HRenderer : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker, Android.Widget.EditText>, TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener, IJavaObject, IDisposable
    {
        private TimePickerDialog dialog = null;

        IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            this.SetNativeControl(new Android.Widget.EditText(Forms.Context));
            this.Control.Click += Control_Click;
            this.Control.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            this.Control.KeyListener = null;
            this.Control.FocusChange += Control_FocusChange;
        }

        void Control_FocusChange(object sender, Android.Views.View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.HasFocus)
            {
                ShowTimePicker();
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);
            }
            else
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
            }
        }

        void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowTimePicker();
        }

        private void ShowTimePicker()
        {
            if (dialog == null)
            {
                dialog = new TimePickerDialog(Forms.Context, this, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, true);
            }

            dialog.Show();
        }

        public void OnTimeSet(Android.Widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
        {
            var time = new TimeSpan(hourOfDay, minute, 0);
            this.Element.SetValue(Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker.TimeProperty, time);

            this.Control.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");

            this.ClearFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

## Xamarin.Forms 2.5+ Answer

Xamarin.Forms v2.5 deprecated `Forms.Context` and also requires an overloaded constructor to be used for Custom Renderers.

To replace `Forms.Context`, we'll need to install the [Plugin.CurrentActivity NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity/).

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;

using TimePickerDemo.CustomControls;
using TimePickerDemo.Droid;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTimePicker24H), typeof(CustomTimePicker24HRenderer))]
namespace TimePickerDemo.Droid
{
    public class CustomTimePicker24HRenderer : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker, Android.Widget.EditText>, TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener, IJavaObject, IDisposable
    {
        private TimePickerDialog dialog = null;

        public CustomTimePicker24HRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            
        }

        Context CurrentContext => Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
        IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            this.SetNativeControl(new Android.Widget.EditText(CurrentContext));
            this.Control.Click += Control_Click;
            this.Control.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            this.Control.KeyListener = null;
            this.Control.FocusChange += Control_FocusChange;
        }

        void Control_FocusChange(object sender, Android.Views.View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.HasFocus)
            {
                ShowTimePicker();
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);
            }
            else
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
            }
        }

        void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowTimePicker();
        }

        private void ShowTimePicker()
        {
            if (dialog == null)
            {
                dialog = new TimePickerDialog(CurrentContext, this, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, true);
            }

            dialog.Show();
        }

        public void OnTimeSet(Android.Widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
        {
            var time = new TimeSpan(hourOfDay, minute, 0);
            this.Element.SetValue(Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker.TimeProperty, time);

            this.Control.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");

            this.ClearFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Their is one more issue with Time Picker, say you selected 1 hour and the value changed binded to Time Picker changed to 2 hrs from backend and when you open the Time Picker it will still open with 1 hour selected not 2 hrs . Any solution ?

Comment: Hey Ashish, happy to help! Can you open a new question and post its link here?

Comment: Hey Brandon, please check the following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279271/24-hours-time-picker-selected-time