# 24 hours Time Picker selected time

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried implementing 24 Hour `Time Picker` as given [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Time-Picker-as-24-Hours-9e9a2431) in XF project.

Also their was an issue with the `Focus` and `Unfocused` events which was solved earlier, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158815/24-hours-timepicker-with-focused-and-unfocused-events/49164354?noredirect=1#comment85559528_49164354)

Now I want to set the time when the `Time Picker` is `Focused`, say I have binded 2 hours to the `Time` property it should open with 2 hours selected, which is not working.

I have noticed the previous time gets binded on the `Time Picker`(time which was selected and `Ok` was clicked), but I want the `Time` which is binded to be selected.
I am using `Xamarin Forms 2.5.0.121934`.

## Android Renderer

I have used `Constant.TimeToBeShowOnPicker.Hours` and `Constant.TimeToBeShowOnPicker.Minutes`
in the code to bind the first value of the Time else by default it is `0:00 hrs` or whatever value you set.

```cs
public class TimePicker24Hours : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker, Android.Widget.EditText>, TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener, IJavaObject, IDisposable
{
    private TimePickerDialog dialog = null;

    IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        this.SetNativeControl(new Android.Widget.EditText(Forms.Context));
        this.Control.Click += Control_Click;
        this.Control.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
        this.Control.KeyListener = null;
        this.Control.FocusChange += Control_FocusChange;
    }

    void Control_FocusChange(object sender, Android.Views.View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HasFocus)
        {
            ShowTimePicker();
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);
        }
        else
        {
            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
        }
    }

    void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowTimePicker();
    }

    private void ShowTimePicker()
    {
        if (dialog == null)
        {
            dialog = new TimePickerDialog(Forms.Context, this, Constant.TimeToBeShowOnPicker.Hours, Constant.TimeToBeShowOnPicker.Minutes, true);
        }

        dialog.Show();
    }

    public void OnTimeSet(Android.Widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        var time = new TimeSpan(hourOfDay, minute, 0);
        this.Element.SetValue(Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker.TimeProperty, time);

        this.Control.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");

        this.ClearFocus();
    }
}
```

## Xamarin.Forms XAML

```xml
<TimePicker x:Name="time_Picker" Time="{Binding SelectedTime}" IsVisible="false" PropertyChanged="TimePicker_PropertyChanged" />
```

And this method is called when `Time Picker` is asked to come to `Focus`

```cs
void EditTime_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var eventArgs = e as TappedEventArgs;
    ViewModel.SelectedTaskItem = (SomeModel)eventArgs.Parameter;

    ViewModel.SelectedTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(ViewModel.SomeModel.Time);
    Constant.TimeToBeShowOnPicker = ViewModel.SelectedTime;

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        time_Picker.Focus();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Ashish! Are you using Xamarin.Forms version 2.5?

Comment: And can you edit the question and copy/paste your Xamarin.Forms code?

Comment: Hey Brandon, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

To ensure the current time is displayed on the Time Picker when it is tapped, we need to include `UpdateTime` in `ShowPicker()`.

### Default Time Value

I also noticed that `Control.Text` always defaults to `DateTime.Now`. To fix this, we just need to set `Control.Text` in `OnElementChanged`.

I've updated the Custom Renderers to check if `Element.Time` is set, and if it is then we can set `Control.Text = Element.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");`

#### Sample App

I've created a sample Xamarin.Forms app here that uses this 24 Hour Time Picker: 
https://github.com/brminnick/24HourTimePicker

## iOS Custom Renderer

```cs
using System;

using Foundation;

using TimePickerDemo;
using TimePickerDemo.iOS;

using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTimePicker24H), typeof(CustomTimePicker24HRenderer))]
namespace TimePickerDemo.iOS
{
    public class CustomTimePicker24HRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var timePicker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
                timePicker.Locale = new NSLocale("no_nb");

                if (Element != null && !Element.Time.Equals(default(TimeSpan)))
                    Control.Text = Element.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
                else
                    Control.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Android Custom Renderer

```cs
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;

using Java.Lang;

using TimePickerDemo;
using TimePickerDemo.Droid;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTimePicker24H), typeof(CustomTimePicker24HRenderer))]
namespace TimePickerDemo.Droid
{
    public class CustomTimePicker24HRenderer : ViewRenderer<TimePicker, Android.Widget.EditText>, TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener, IJavaObject, IDisposable
    {
        TimePickerDialog _dialog;

        public CustomTimePicker24HRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        Context CurrentContext => Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
        IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

        public void OnTimeSet(Android.Widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
        {
            var time = new TimeSpan(hourOfDay, minute, 0);
            Element.SetValue(TimePicker.TimeProperty, time);

            Control.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");

            ClearFocus();
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            SetNativeControl(new Android.Widget.EditText(CurrentContext));

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Click += Control_Click;
                Control.FocusChange += Control_FocusChange;

                if (Element != null && !Element.Time.Equals(default(TimeSpan)))
                    Control.Text = Element.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
                else
                    Control.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
            }
        }

        void Control_FocusChange(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.HasFocus)
            {
                ShowTimePicker();
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);
            }
            else
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
            }
        }

        void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => ShowTimePicker();

        void ShowTimePicker()
        {
            if (_dialog == null)
                _dialog = new TimePickerDialog(CurrentContext, this, Element.Time.Hours, Element.Time.Minutes, true);

            _dialog.UpdateTime(Element.Time.Hours, Element.Time.Minutes);

            _dialog.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Brandon , that worked like a charm! Thank you for the help !