# Xamarin Forms Timepicker Format Input String not in the correct format

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, format, timepicker

I have a hopefully simple question for you. I created a Timepicker for my Xamarinapp. This Timepicker should get the 24hours format. So in den .xaml File I did that.

```
<TimePicker Format="HH:mm" x:Name="Time"/>
```

In the view its no problem, but whenever I try to save it in that format in my code I get the error "Input string was not in a correct format".

My code looks like this

```
time = Time.Time.ToString(Time.Format)
```

Maybe someone of you sees the Problem, because I don't get it.

Thanks for the help and Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct format should be:

```
   string time = Time.Time.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

You can check the valid format in this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_TimeSpan_ToString_System_String_):

```
  string[] fmts = { "c", "g", "G", @"hh\:mm\:ss", "%m' min.'" };
```

And you can check document about the [standard-timespan-format-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) and [custom-timespan-format-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)

Here are also some links you can refer:

[time-picker-as-24-hours-format-in-xamarin-forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/time-picker-as-24-hours-format-in-xamarin-forms/)

[24-hours-time-picker-selected-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279271/24-hours-time-picker-selected-time)

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) for TimeSpan, "HH" is not a valid format string.  The XAML parser may be doing something that converts it to "hh", which is valid.

Try this instead

```
<TimePicker Format="hh:mm" x:Name="Time"/>
```